# Thymeleaf does not resolve model via spring boot and controller

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wanted to play around with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. Therefore I loaded my Spring Boot App via Spring Initialzr and set Web and Thymeleaf as dependencies.
Sadly I cannot resolve any dynamic html only static ones.

When requesting `localhost:8080/` I receive this: `The message is:${message}`

Gonna provide some code to show off my setup (most minimal code possible)

**WebApp.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView handler() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("twitter");
    mav.addObject("message", "message");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

**twitter.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> </meta>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
The message is:${message}

</body>
</html>
```

**pom.mxl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must change your view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> </meta>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        The message is: <span th:text="${message}"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wait... don't tell me "th" is a taglib for thymeleaf acronym. I always thought it stands for "table-header" which is used by html. I have very minor experience with HTML tbh.

Comment: Please read the [Thymeleaf's documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/#natural-templates) :)

Comment: Yea I read that but since its using a table in the example I was not aware that "th" was a thymeleaf specific keyword